# Temporarily disable set_error_handler

Tags: php, error-handling

I am using a custom error handler using `set_error_handler()`.  All works perfect until I get to the "Do buggy script" part.  This buggy script is some integration into http://osticket.com/.  Note that I have enabled all errors on the base installation of ostickets without my integration, and I get the same errors, so I know it is not a flaw in my integration.

When I run the script shown below, I get approximately 200 errors written to my log and emailed to me.

My desire is to temporarily disable `set_error_handler` right before this script, and then re-enable it right when it is complete.

How is this accomplished?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler("my_error_handler");

//Do normal script

//I wish to disable set_error_handler here

//Do buggy script

//I wish to re-enable set_error_handler here

//Do normal script

//Complete

function my_error_handler($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) {
    $message = "An error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line: $e_message (error no: $e_number)";
    syslog(LOG_INFO,'my_error_handler: '.$message);
    $e_vars='<pre>'.print_r($e_vars, 1).'</pre>';
    ob_start();
    debug_print_backtrace();
    $backtrace = ob_get_clean();
    if (in_array(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 5), array('local', '127.0', '192.1'))) {
        echo "<div class='error'>{$message}</div><p>e_vars:</p><pre>{$e_vars}</pre><p>debug_print_backtrace:</p><pre>{$backtrace}</pre>";

    } else { 
        error_log ($message.' e_vars=> '.$e_vars, 1, 'errors@testsite.com');
        if ( ($e_number != E_NOTICE) && ($e_number < 2048)) {
            echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div>';
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Within the OSTicket code, bootstrap.init() sets up error reporting.  I don't wish to modify the original OSTicket code as doing so will make it more difficult to upgrade to new versions.

```
    #Error reporting...Good idea to ENABLE error reporting to a file. i.e display_errors should be set to false
    $error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE;
    if (defined('E_STRICT')) # 5.4.0
        $error_reporting &= ~E_STRICT;
    if (defined('E_DEPRECATED')) # 5.3.0
        $error_reporting &= ~(E_DEPRECATED | E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    error_reporting($error_reporting); //Respect whatever is set in php.ini (sysadmin knows better??)

    #Don't display errors
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

Comment: Set error_reporting to 0 and test in your handler of the error_reporting is 0. If So Just return false. Fyi Thats how php Does it internal as well when u use `@` to supress warnings

Comment: @DarkBee  Thanks DarkBee.  Within the OSTicket code, error reporting is defined (see the end of my original post) so I don't know if I could do as you recommend.

Comment: Just do something like: $old = error_reporting(); error_reporting(0); //some shitty code here; error_reporting($old);

Comment: But won't that get overridden by the OSTicket script that I showed at the end of my post?

Comment: Im not sure im following. This will temporarily disable the error_reporting and will reset to the $old level as you reset it. So error_reporting will hold the value before u ran the buggy script. I assume the osticket code is executed At the start of the script So $old will hold whatever valure was set by it

Comment: Yes, doing as you say will disable error_reporting, but then when the ostickets script is executed, it will set error reporting, and since I have set_error_handler setup, they will be logged.

Comment: Then check inside your handler If error_reporting is 0 and return false and  add @ a before your function call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set another do nothing function:

```
$my_error_handler = set_error_handler(function() { return true; });
// call OSTicket here
set_error_handler($my_error_handler);
```

Change `return true` to `return false` to execute PHP internal error handler.